# how to make icons stick with their texts?

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to build a responsive upper-header[as you see in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlsi5.png).

The problem as you see the message icon stay hanged while its text goes
down whenever the width between 757 and 575.

I'm still new in css in general and bootstrap 4.

Thank you in Advance!

```css
.upper-bar {
  font-family: Times;
  background-color: #007872;
  color: #fff;
}

.upper-bar a {
  color: #fff;
}

.upper-bar-left,
.upper-bar-right {
  margin: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
  .upper-bar-left:first-child,
  .upper-bar-right:first-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="upper-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm upper-bar-left text-sm-left">
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 00000009890
        <i class="far fa-envelope"></i><a href="mailto:lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx"> lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm upper-bar-right text-sm-right">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i> LOrem Ipsum 0, 00098 Loremipsum
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bxREoK?editors=1100
```

Comment: I had used the same info that was in codepen. As far as i know, codepen is also public (because i could access that info) so how come posting it on Stackoverflow is any different(info sharing on Stackoverflow is as much public as codepen). Still I deleted  that answer and posted a new one just for your benefit :)

Comment: I saw private information (number, address, email). I'm not sure if you took it from another pen i had or if I had eye problem for a minute XD. Anyway, thank you a lot for your info! Peace!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the envelope icon and email anchor in a span with `text-nowrap` class on it

```
<span class="text-nowrap">
    <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
    <a href="mailto:lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx"> lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx</a>
</span>
```

See [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow) for information on text-nowrap

```css
.upper-bar {
  font-family: Times;
  background-color: #007872;
  color: #fff;
}

.upper-bar a {
  color: #fff;
}

.upper-bar-left,
.upper-bar-right {
  margin: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/2972279885.js"></script>

<div class="upper-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm upper-bar-left text-sm-left">
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 0542 1421455
        <span class="text-nowrap">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
          <a href="mailto:lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx"> lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx</a>
         </span>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm upper-bar-right text-sm-right">
        <i class="fas fa-map-marker"></i> LOrem Ipsum 0, 00098 Loremipsum
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also consider adding the class "fa-fw" to the icons, so they get equal width. Looks a bit better when there are multiple icons under/over each other.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can do like this:

html

```
<div class="icon-text">
<i class="fab fa-facebook-f">
<p> Your text</p>
</div>
```

css

```
.icon-text {
display: inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this way.

CSS Code:

```
.left-style{
float:left;
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-sm upper-bar-left text-sm-left">
        <span class="left-style"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 00000009890</span>
        <span class="left-style"><i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
<a href="mailto:lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx"> lorem_ipsuml@xxxxx.xx</a></span>
</div>
```